# Junit Runner cannot be resolved type

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I am using Springboot 2.1.3.RELEASE version.

Recently I have written DAO, Service, Component and Integration layer test cases using Junit 5 and Mockito framework all these test cases are working fine.

If I want to run all these test cases then individually I have to run each test classes.
To overcome this problem I have implemented Spring Suite using Junit 5.

Recently I made changes in build.gradle file or added **junit-platform-runner** dependency.

After adding this dependency my Suite class throwing below exception.

**The type org.junit.runner.Runner cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files**

Here is my Spring Suite class

**SpringSuitTest.java**

```
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasses;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectClasses({someclasseshere.class})
public class SpringSuitTest {

}
```

My dependencies

```
// Runtime dependencies

testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.2")
testRuntime("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.5.2")
testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.2")

testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-core:2.27.0")
testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.27.0")
```

I googled a lot but none of the solutions worked for me.
Recently I have added Junit runner dependency, I am considering may be invalid version I have added

```
testRuntime("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.5.2")
```

[image]

Any idea why I am getting such exception.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After adding below 2 dependencies resolved the issue.

```
testImplementation group: 'org.junit.vintage', name: 'junit-vintage-engine', version: '5.3.2'

testImplementation group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-runner', version: '1.2.0'
```